# Redirect New (+) button of Document Library to new upload form of Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

1. How can I redirect New (+) button in document library of SharePoint 2013 to a new form to upload file.
2. One more thing is that I have added some columns in the Library and its available in the "All Documents" view. but while I am trying to upload doc or pulling the library as a webpart that columns are not getting reflected. Can you please suggest to make that happen

Answer (score 1):

To change the default new item form, open the site in SharePoint Designer > go to the library > change the form in the library page. Refer [this](https://support.office.com/en-ZA/article/Create-a-custom-list-form-using-SharePoint-Designer-917d8fdb-ee00-4441-adb3-a94612d1d105)

For the second issue, check if the columns are present in the view and in the content type if you are using a content type. Refer [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850690(v=office.12).aspx) for changing column to the content type, and [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-change-a-view-6b601dd9-aa0e-45a5-937d-eefc2f81a731#bm5) for changing column to the view

Comment: I will  try the first one. For the second one I am not using any content type column. Though I have added those columns in the view still they are not appearing while I am uploading any file.

Comment: Make sure you have, `add to all content types` checked when you are creating the column. The default content type for a doc lib is `document`. IF not in it, go to doc lib settings > content type > select content type > go to columns section > add from existing site / List columns > add the columns you wanna see. You should be able to see the changes in the new item /  upload file form